# Get text of label after Touch it [tableView]

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I customized the tableView cell which I set a label of time & What I need if I touch/click the label it show the text of that label.

Here is the time label set:

```
cell.time.text = @"5 mins ago";
cell.time.tag = 1;
UITapGestureRecognizer* tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapAction:)];
[cell.time setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[cell.time addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

So when I tapped the label must do the below

```
-(void)tapAction:(id)sender
{
    // I want to get the text of that label for above example must return

    // 5 mins ago
}
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: so whats the problem?

Comment: Do one thing dude . Instead of the label take the custom button . Then apply logic i.e first get the cell and then button from the cell . Then ask for title to the button .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access tap View

```
-(void)tapAction:(id)sender
{
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRec = (UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender;
    UILabel *label = (UILabel *)tapRec.view;
    NSLog(@"%@",label.text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use instead the delegate methods instead of setting a gesturerecognizer on your cell?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

}
```

You can then extract the row from indexPath, and know which cell was selected.

Answer (score 0):

use below code

```
cell.time.text = @"5 mins ago";
cell.time.tag = [indexpath.row];
UITapGestureRecognizer* tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapAction:)];
[cell.time setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[cell.time addGestureRecognizer:tap];


-(void)tapAction:(id)sender
{
 UIbutton *btn = (UIbutton *)sender
 Nsstring *str = [btn.text]
// I want to get the text of that label for above example must return

// 5 mins ago
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
-(void)tapAction:(id)sender
{
    UITapGestureRecognizer *recognizer = (UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender;
    UILabel *label = (UILabel *)recognizer.view;
    NSString *text = label.text;
}
```